# UFW give errors and won't auto start at boot

Tags: server, firewall, ufw

I just tried to enable ufw on my server, it gave me this error :

> ERROR: problem running ufw-init

When I tried the second time, it worked.
When I tried to set the default rule "sudo ufw default deny" i get the same error and it never works. Also, when I reboot the system, the firewall is inactive!

Earlier when I hired a person to setup my server, I can remeber him saying that Mediatemple servers have a problem with UFW! How can I fix this?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ufw/+bug/521359

Comment: that bug reports said the fix is released but I have the same error now with fresh installs

Comment: This is happening to me fresh install. Really pissing me off.